# JavaFX динамическое обновление текста в label

Tags: java, javafx

Пишу простенький чат клиент с *JavaFX*, необходимо обновить текст в `label` (там будут показываться сообщения). Как можно динамически обновлять текст в этом `label`? С *JavaFX* почти не знаком и пока не хочу его изучать, использовал его только для того, чтобы не делать чат консольным, так что скорее всего исользую `label` неверно.

Comment: приведите пример кода, как вы используете label

Comment: я его ещё даже не использую, пробывал создать метод `sendMess(String message){
label.setText(message);
}`
и вызываю егов другом классе, но это не работает, т.к. метод main у меня просто вызвает        ` launch(args);` и даже если сразу после этого поставить sendMess("test");  и получиться `main(String[]args){
launch(args);
sendMess("test");
}` то ничего не произойдет, т.к. пока launch не завершиться после него ничего не вызовется. Я вот подумал может что-то для динамического обновления надо в методе start(Stage stage) вызывать

Answer (score 2):

> нельзя в другом потоке это делать, т.к. вылезет `Not on FX application thread`

Используйте `Platform.runLater(() -> label.setText("new text"));` - это позволит изменить содержимое `label` из потока, не относящегося к `FX application thread`.

P.S.: Так же вы можете использовать `javafx.concurrent.Task`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать многопоточность

В первом потоке инициализируете интерфейс, во втором обновляете его

Comment: а как его обновлять? я чесно говоря думал, что вопрос очень тривеальный и решить его легко, так что врятли это надо через много поточность. Тем более что мне кажется что таким способ не получиться, ведь скорее всего придется каждый раз label пересоздавать

Comment: используйте ваш же метод sendMess

Comment: нельзя в другом потоке это делать, т.к. вылезет `Not on FX application thread`